# Import DHCP to WORKGROUP Server from DOMAIN Server using powershell function

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I am replacing all of our branch office Domain Controllers. Part of the process involves importing DHCP scope/leases. Per outlined parameters I need to try to do this while the new server is on-site and connected to switch but PRIOR to domain join. I am trying to pass the scriptblock as a function so I can add -credential but I am receiving an error: "Parameter Set cannot be resolved using specified named parameters."

This does work when running with the credentials specified in the (get-credential) call when being used from a domain joined PC. The credentials supplied are domain admin credentials.

```
function Export-DHCP {
       param(
        $oldserver,
        [ValidateNotNull()]
        [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
        [System.Management.Automation.Credential()]
        $Credential = [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]::Empty        
    )
        $null = Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock{
            Export-DhcpServer -ComputerName $OldServer -File "C:\migration\exports\dhcpexport.xml" -leases
        } -Credential $Credential
}

$oldserver= 'servername.domain'
Export-Dhcp -computername $oldserver -credential (get-credential)
```

Comment: In your function call you are using the parameter -computername, but your function doesn't have this parameter but instead a parameter $oldserver?

Comment: My understanding is that functions inherently support computer name and a few other parameters without explicitly calling them. I did get it to work. Thank you for your response!